# Aligning problem in mathmode

Tags: alignment

In the MWE I cannot achieve aligning the plus signs being outside the brackets (version 1).
In version 2 it is "almost" as I wish to have it, but spacing left and right of the "+" are too large.
In version 3 I tried \makemathbox, but that fails.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
Version 1
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
H &= \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} \right) \\
  &< \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Version 2
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
H &= \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right) &&+& \left( \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} \right) \\
  &< \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} \right) &&+& \left( \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Version 3
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
H &= \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} \right) \\
  &< \mathmakebox[\widthof{$\left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right)$}][c]{\left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} \right)} + \left( \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decide if you want to align at the =/< sign or at the +. If you want both, the space needs to be inserted somewhere.

Version 2 modified without the forced space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
H = \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right) &+ \left( \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} \right) \\
  < \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} \right) &+ \left( \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or make the 1 the same width as 1/2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newlength{\foo}
\settowidth{\foo}{$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
H = \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right) &+ \left( \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} \right) \\
  < \left( \makebox[\foo]{$\displaystyle 1$} + \frac{1}{2} \right) &+ \left( \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to use the `alignat` environment, which gives ou control on the spacing between the two columns.

I added a variant, with `the medium-sized  fractions from`nccmath`  which look nicer for numeric fractions, in my opinion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
H & = & \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \right) &+ \left( \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} \right) \\
   & < & \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} \right) &+ \left( \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \right)
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation*}
\bigskip

\begin{equation*}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
H & = & \left( \mfrac{1}{2} + \mfrac{1}{2} \right) &+ \left( \mfrac{1}{4} + \mfrac{1}{4} \right) \\
   & < & \left( 1 + \mfrac{1}{2} \right) &+ \left( \mfrac{1}{3} + \mfrac{1}{4} \right)
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]